# org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: in JBOSS 7

Tags: java

While I am trying to access webservice url from GateIn3.4(JBOSS AS 7) it is redirecting to `org.exoplatform.services.rest.impl.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl` and the following error occurs   `org.exoplatform.services.rest.impl.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl.<init>(ResponseImpl.java:217).`   I am attaching the entire log here.

```
18:11:32,148 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1) Caused by: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
18:11:32,149 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:839)
18:11:32,149 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:816)
18:11:32,150 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:743)
18:11:32,150 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:717)
18:11:32,151 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:344)
18:11:32,151 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:469)
18:11:32,152 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.services.WorkflowProcessService.getBusinessRuleList(WorkflowProcessService.java:455)
18:11:32,152 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.services.WorkflowProcessService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b715c2f2.invoke(<generated>)
18:11:32,153 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
18:11:32,154 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
18:11:32,154 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
18:11:32,155 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
18:11:32,156 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
18:11:32,156 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
18:11:32,157 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.services.WorkflowProcessService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4bcf15b7.getBusinessRuleList(<generated>)
18:11:32,158 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.view.bean.BusinessRuleBean.getBusinessRuleList(BusinessRuleBean.java:69)
18:11:32,159 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  ... 307 more
18:11:32,159 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
18:11:32,159 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.exoplatform.services.rest.impl.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl.<init>(ResponseImpl.java:217)
18:11:32,160 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.exoplatform.services.rest.impl.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl.clone(ResponseImpl.java:284)
18:11:32,161 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.setResponseBuilder(AbstractClient.java:381)
18:11:32,161 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:829)
18:11:32,162 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  ... 322 more*
```

Expecting a solution...

I can't do deep cloning since the class is from a third party source. Is there some other way to solve this. When I am running the code in a  sample progrm it is working fine. But the issue happens when executing  from within the application which is deployed in gateIn 3.6 with JBOSS7. Is any other configurations should I do ?Or can it be due to some jar mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the constructor of `ResponseBuilderImpl`. When it call `clone` to instantiate the object instance it might not copy some field values. You need to use *deep clone* technique.